# Saving changes to database during FormClosing fails

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am unable to determine why the following code fails to save changes to database during FormClosing event:

```
private void frmClient_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (bAreChanges)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to save the changes to the database?",
            "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            using (var context = new SomeEntities()) {
                 var value = "abc";
                 context.sometable.Add(new sometable() {somefield = value} );
                 context.SaveChanges();
                 //the same exact code works when executed from a simple button click that is placed on this form.
            }

            this.Validate(); // even added this line as suggested in another Stackoverflow question
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps some part of SaveChanges() is asynchronous and therefore the Form disposes before the database operation is executed?

Edit:  This is a child form, not the main form - the application keeps running after this form is closed. If this is somehow relevant.

Comment: Did you attach the debugger to the code and step through line by line? That's the first step in figuring out what's actually happening.

Comment: Did just now, it goes exactly as it should and yet there are no changes in the database. The same exact code works when executed from a button rather than in a FormClosing event.

Comment: What happens if you put `e.Cancel = true;` before the `using` part? Does it save the changes?

Comment: Tried that also as suggested in another thread on Stackoverflow, but it still does not save the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `this.Validate()` before the database operations made it work. I would, however, like to know why is that relevant in this case.